# postgres - with recursive

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I expected the following to return all the tuples, resolving each parent in the hierarchy up to the top, but it only returns the lowest levels (whose ID is specified in the query).  How do I return the whole tree for a given level_id?

```
create table level(
level_id int,
level_name text,
parent_level int);

 insert into level values (197,'child',177), (  177, 'parent', 3 ), (  2, 'grandparent',  null  );

WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(level_id, levelparent) AS (
 SELECT level_id, parent_level 
 FROM level 
 where level_id = 197

UNION ALL
SELECT t.level_id, t.parent_level
FROM level t, recursetree rt 
WHERE rt.level_id = t.parent_level
)

SELECT * FROM recursetree;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your `(2, 'grandparent', null)` should be `(3, 'grandparent', null)` if it really is a grandparent. Secondly, your (implicit) join condition in the recursive half of your query is backwards, you want to get the parent out of `rt.levelparent` rather than `t.parent_level`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(level_id, levelparent) AS (
    SELECT level_id, parent_level 
    FROM level 
    WHERE level_id = 197

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.level_id, t.parent_level
    FROM level t JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.levelparent = t.level_id
    -- join condition fixed and ANSI-ified above
)
SELECT * FROM recursetree;
```

Comment: How do I get all the children on the same level? Right now I get only one row on each level.

Comment: @zimmi: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Let's say I have two rows which have the same parent_id. With this piece of code, I get only one of them in the result set.

Comment: Have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac381/1. You should get User, Manager1 and Manager2 as a result, but you only get one of managers.

Comment: @zimmi: But there's nothing in there links to Manager2. The links go Admin -> Manager1 -> User, there's nothing in there that points toward Manager2 so the Manager2 -> User link will not be followed.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. But would there be a way to make it followed? I mean what if wanted to get a chain of all the roles going from User to Admin? Both Manager1 and Manager2 inherit from User.

Comment: @zimmi: You'd start at User and reverse the link direction: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac381/3

Comment: That's an interesting idea, however I need to stop the recursion somehow. If I have role chain like User -> Manager -> Admin -> Superadmin and I would be logged in as Admin, I should not be able to see Superadmin role in the results.

Comment: @zimmi: The recursion will stop on its when the JOIN fails, if you want it to stop sooner then you need to express your stop-conditions in the query. Perhaps this would be easier if your data model was reversed.