# Postgresql query for getting n-level parent-child relation stored in a single table

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, database

I have a table denoting parent-child relations. The relations can go n-level deep.

I have created a sample table using the following query:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE relations_rel_id_seq
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MAXVALUE
    NO MINVALUE
    CACHE 1;
CREATE TABLE relations(
    rel_id bigint DEFAULT nextval('relations_rel_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    rel_name text,
    rel_display text,
    rel_parent bigint
);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/59319/1)

I need to query the table and display the parent-child relations hierarchically. I'm still not getting an idea regarding how to query n-level deep using sql query.

For the sqlfiddle eg, the expected hierarchy of output:

```
rel1
    rel11
        rel111
        rel112
            rel1121
rel2
    rel21
        rel211
        rel212
```

**N.B:** The value n, in `n-level` is unknown.

**DB Design:**

> Is there any better way such a relation can be expressed in the
>   database for easy querying.?

Comment: You're probably looking for WITH RECURSIVE, there's an example [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14491526/479863).

Comment: @muistooshort, Thanks for the suggestion. 'll look into it. Do you have any suggestion for alternative db design, that can make it easier for querying and retrieving relations in such cases?

Comment: @saji89 Read [`this`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) page of the manual. It describes `WITH RECURSIVE` queries you need.

Comment: @saji89 BTW It is good to mention your RDBMS version. Recursive queries aren't available in PostgreSQL below 8.4.

Comment: I find the `rel_parent` structure that you have to be the most natural design for trees; it makes sense and, given WITH RECURSIVE, is easy to work with for all the usual operations. You could look at "nested sets" and "materialized paths" I suppose.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With Postgres you can use a recursive common table expression:

```
with recursive rel_tree as (
   select rel_id, rel_name, rel_parent, 1 as level, array[rel_id] as path_info
   from relations 
   where rel_parent is null
   union all
   select c.rel_id, rpad(' ', p.level * 2) || c.rel_name, c.rel_parent, p.level + 1, p.path_info||c.rel_id
   from relations c
     join rel_tree p on c.rel_parent = p.rel_id
)
select rel_id, rel_name
from rel_tree
order by path_info;
```

SQLFiddle based on your example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/59319/19

(I replaced the spaces for indention with underscores as SQLFiddle doesn't display the spaces correctly)

Comment: Great answer, exactly what the OP is looking for! But there is a little mistake in the `rpad(..)` part, changed it to `rpad('', p.level * 2, ' ')`. Again space is replaced with '_' on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/59319/38).

Comment: Just checked the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html): space is the default fill character (optional 3rd parameter), so I had to use the '_' fill character explicitly on SQLFiddle.

Comment: +1, Wow. `Postgresql` doesn't cease to surprise me. Thankyou.

Comment: For a moment I was at a loss as to how to use a normal `with` expression together with `with recursive`. Seems like you're supposed to put the `with` expression inside the `with recursive`.

Comment: @mkataja: no, you just add it. `with recursive first_cte (...), second_cte (...) select * from second_cte`. The `recursive` keyword is only required *once* together with the initial `with` keyword - regardless which CTE is recursive.

Comment: Heh, that makes sense. Somehow I thought the `recursive` keyword needs to be together with the actual recursive CTE(s).